# What's wrong with this proof?

Tags: fake-proofs

> $$e^i = (e^i)^{(2\pi/2\pi)} = (e^{2\pi i})^{1/2\pi} = 1^{1/2\pi} = 1.$$

[I first saw this one many years ago, written on the wall of a bathroom stall in the Princeton University math department.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94742/examples-of-interesting-false-proofs)

Comment: It is not true that $(z^a)^b=z^{ab}$ in general. If you search this site you will find thorough discussions of this fact.

Comment: They are taking the root of a complex number by writing $x^{1/2\pi}$. And it isn't even a rational root. But i am still not convinced :D.